# Cannot determine module type ("PYTHON_MODULE") for the following module

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea

When i opened the iDEA and try to run my project , i got the below error.

> 2:12 PM   Unknown Module Type
>                 Cannot determine module type ("PYTHON_MODULE") for the following module:"test"
>                 The module will be treated as a Unknown module.

I dint make any changes as far i remember and the project was working until last week.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
madhu

Comment: Install Python plugin.

Answer (score 10):

.idea hidden folder is the project settings created by any Intellij IDEA IDE. The .idea folder must be clear -- no conflict in dependencies. E.g., for C++ cmake based project you need C++ ide such as Clion. Clion configures .idea based on Cmake projects.

Now, your problem when you try to open Cmake C++ project into non C++ IDE (such as Pycharm), the .idea folder conflicts. And you see such above problems.

To fix this issue, just delete the .idea folder. And re open your IDE.